# How do I get an variable outside of an array in PHP for MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, opencart

I have a large `foreach` loop that has other loops and conditionals inside it. At the top of the code I am modifying I wish to a value out of the `option_data` array - how is this done?

```
foreach ($this->cart->getProducts() as $product) {

    $option_data = array();
    foreach ($product['option'] as $option) {
        if ($option['type'] != 'file') {
            $value = $option['option_value'];   
        } else {
            $filename = $this->encryption->decrypt($option['option_value']);

            $value = utf8_substr($filename, 0, utf8_strrpos($filename, '.'));
        }               
        $option_data[] = array(     
            'cid'       => $option['option_value_id'], // WANT THIS CID VALUE                          
            'name'  => $option['name'],
            'value' => (utf8_strlen($value) > 20 ? utf8_substr($value, 0, 20) . '..' : $value),
            'type'  => $option['type']
        );
    }


    $sql_get_colour_image=mysql_query("
    SELECT
        imagefb_url
    FROM
        `ocm1__product_image_fb`
    WHERE 
        `pid`=`".$product['product_id']."`
    AND
        `cid`= //GOES HERE
    ");
```

Comment: cid exist in a inner loop from the context your trying to refer it

Comment: How do I take `$option['option_value_id']` out and place it in my MySQL query? Thanks for the reply

Comment: which `$option['option_value_id']` the first or the last ?

Comment: I want to get the `cid` from the `$option_data[]` and place it in the `cid` call of the MySQL

Comment: $option_data[] can have multiple cid values

Comment: Yes I know just tell me how to do it please

Comment: Which value do you want, do you want all of them is my question man

Comment: Yes, just show me to examples at least. My question is clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
    $option_data = array();
    foreach ($product['option'] as $option) {
    if ($option['type'] != 'file') {
        $value = $option['option_value'];   
    } else {
        $filename = $this->encryption->decrypt($option['option_value']);

        $value = utf8_substr($filename, 0, utf8_strrpos($filename, '.'));
    }               
    $option_data[] = array(     
        'cid'       => $option['option_value_id'], // WANT THIS CID VALUE                          
        'name'  => $option['name'],
        'value' => (utf8_strlen($value) > 20 ? utf8_substr($value, 0, 20) . '..' : $value),
        'type'  => $option['type']
    );
    $sql_get_colour_image=mysql_query("
        SELECT
          imagefb_url
        FROM
          `ocm1__product_image_fb`
        WHERE 
          `pid`=".$product['product_id']."
          AND `cid`= ".$option['option_value_id']."
    ");
  }
```

Alternative you can:

```
$option_data = array();
$cids = array();
foreach ($product['option'] as $option) {
    if ($option['type'] != 'file') {
        $value = $option['option_value'];   
    } else {
        $filename = $this->encryption->decrypt($option['option_value']);

        $value = utf8_substr($filename, 0, utf8_strrpos($filename, '.'));
    }               
    $option_data[] = array(     
        'cid'       => $option['option_value_id'], // WANT THIS CID VALUE                          
        'name'  => $option['name'],
        'value' => (utf8_strlen($value) > 20 ? utf8_substr($value, 0, 20) . '..' : $value),
        'type'  => $option['type']
    );
    $cids[] = $option['option_value_id'];
}
$sql_get_colour_image=mysql_query("
    SELECT
        imagefb_url
    FROM
        `ocm1__product_image_fb`
    WHERE 
        `pid`=".$product['product_id']."
    AND
        `cid` IN (".implode(",",$cids).")
");
```

Comment: you moved his query to the inner loop, i don;t think thats what he wants

Comment: That was the problem. I had to move it into the inner loop to get the value too! Thanks for noticing that inner loop too.

Comment: @DevZer0 well that was the only option ... or to have `cid IN (implode array)`

Comment: Can you show me an implode in that answer just for future and learning